# What does "P. C. MOUNTING" stand for?

Tags: datasheet, diagram, jargon

In [this datasheet](http://lgrws01.grayhill.com/web1/images/ProductImages/H-07.pdf), last page, what does "P. C. MOUNTING" mean in the diagrams?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Printed Circuit mounting. This part of the drawing shows the recommended pad size, hole size and spacing on the PCB. Copy this when you create a "footprint" for the switch in your PCB layout system, and the switch should fit the PCB perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, what are the recommended pad size and hole size? I only see one diameter (1.09mm), and I don't know if that corresponds to the pad size or hole size.

Comment: For this part, you are correct, they only give the hole size. More generally you will see both, or recommended pad size for surface-mount parts. As this is a switch, liable to rough handling, my inclination is to use the largest pads I can, to fix it firmly to the board.

Answer (score 3):

P.C. = Printed Circuit (as in PCB). And "P. C. MOUNTING" just means the recommended footprint of that component.